# Checking If Position Exists in Nested List

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm trying to solve a Python coding problem. Given a certain array containing only 1's and 0's I must write a program that returns an array following a few rules:

1. Each 1 must be replaced with a 9
2. Each 0 must be replaced with the amount of 1's in its immediate surroundings (above, below, left, right)

I'm having trouble with the edges and corners, since I must first check if a certain position exists to then check if it is a 1. The solution I have right now is to make use of 8 'if' statements, but it looks quite ugly and seems inefficient:

```
  counter = 0
  if x+1 < len(board):
    if board[x+1][y] == 9:
      counter += 1
  if y+1 < len(board[i]):
    if board[x][y+1] == 9:
      counter += 1
  if x-1 >= 0:
    if board[x-1][y] == 9:
      counter += 1
  if y-1 >= 0:
    if board[x][y-1] == 9:
      counter += 1
  board[x][y] = counter
```

While it does work, I was wondering if there was an easier/cleaner solution I could implement.

Comment: Is your input a 2D array? Show an example of input and output.

Comment: Maybe ```counter += board[x+1][y] // 9```

Comment: Please supply sample data and a complete program that can be run against the data.  If you believe your code is working correctly, make really sure that the code gives the right result for the data you're providing.  This way, others can play with your code and try out their suggestions before presenting them to you in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me how that code snippet fits in your solution, but if your problem is the neighborhood iteration, a common trick is to pre-define the offsets:

```py
...

# suppose the current position is (x,y)
for dx, dy in [(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]:
    tx = x + dx # t as in target
    ty = y + dy
    if 0 <= tx < len(board) and 0 <= ty < len(board[tx]):
        # the position (tx, ty) exists, do whatever you want with it
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use logical short-circuiting:

```
if x+1 < len(board) and board[x+1][y] == 9:
  counter += 1
```

If the first clause is `False`, the second won't be evaluated at all.  You're safe from that exception.

Next you can simplify the math: harness the fact that class `bool` is a derived from `int`: `False` is 0; `True` is 1.

```
counter += x+1 < len(board) and board[x+1][y] == 9
```

Now, you can just put all four liens in a row, or even combine all four Boolean expressions into a single `+=` statement.

Comment: Regarding the second suggestion...I don't like relying on the implicit conversion between boolean and integer. It doesn't read well as it assumes knowledge that not all Python programmers will have, and is a little obtuse in any case.  I'd suggest the alternative: `counter += 1 if (x+1 < len(board) and board[x+1][y] == 9) else 0`.  Not as slick looking, but preferable IMHO.